# HTTP POST request in C

Tags: c, mingw32, msys2

Is possible to send HTTP POST Request in a simple way? (like python:

```
import requests
requests.post(ip, data)
```

I am using msys2 and editing a 1996 file.  I tried some libs like httprequest, curl, etc but isn't working, I am trying to use native C (when I say native, means no libs or headers). Is it possible?

Comment: libcurl is a good solution, if you are having trouble with it then maybe post a question [showing your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It's not possible to interact with the operating system without using headers or libraries

Comment: It is only "simple" in python because someone wrote a library for it in C.

Comment: You need to install a library. C isn't built for web-developement so you *won't* find any thing in the standard library that's useful.